# Find out if you're viewing a taxonomy page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Clicking on a Taxonomy term generally takes you to a page showing several nodes which use that term. Is there a way to find out if you're viewing a specific vocabulary and save it to a variable? That way you can change the layout at will:

```
<?php if( $is_vocabulary_fruits ) : ?>
    Load this layout
<?php if( $is_vocabulary_cars ) : ?>
    Another layout different from the first
<?php else : ?>
    Nope, use this layout instead
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm looking to place this in `page.tpl.php`. This means that the markup outside of the `node.tpl.php` is changed when viewing a taxonomy and not the node itself. How is this done in my template.php file?

Answer (score 2):

When a taxonomy page is rendered, the template file used is [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7) that receives, among other variables, the `$term` variable, which contains the term object for the taxonomy term associated to those nodes.
Basing on the vocabulary that owns that taxonomy term, you can change the layout of the page.

If you want to find out in page.tpl.php the taxonomy term associated with the nodes shown in the page (where the page's URL is example.com/taxonomy/term/[tid]), then you can use the following code:

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
```

If the page's URL is not example.com/taxonomy/term/[tid], then the function returns `FALSE`. The code can also be executed in a preprocess function, such as `hook_preprocess_page()`.

Comment: This works but it still falls back to using the default `page.tpl.php`. I'm trying to look for a way so I can add extra markup to `page.tpl.php` by checking using the variables above which then loads the taxonomy-term.tpl.php file.

Comment: The page.tpl.php file is always used for all the pages; it does not fall back on using it. First the template for the taxonomy term page is used, and then the template for the page is used. It is the same for a node; first node.tpl.php is used and then page.tpl.php is used.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways to have different layouts based on vocabulary. One is through template suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/1089656. You would need to do your own template suggestion for your vocabularies and you can have different markup or classes.

Another way would be to add a vocabulary body class based on the taxonomy and you change the layout that way like:

```
.vocabulary-fruits #main {width:600px; float:right}
```

Look at: http://drupal.org/node/1072806